# PHP function only calling one parameter and I need it to call a bunch

Tags: php, function

Hi there I have a simple form that I am trying to validate using PHP. My problem is that my function that I have created only calls in one field instead of multiple fields.

The form can be seen below

```
<form method="post" action="cms-nlcreate-process.php" id="formcreatenew" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <fieldset>
                <legend>General</legend>
                <label>Issue no:</label>

                <?php echo valuerequired('svissueno') ?>

                    <input type="text" name="txtissueno" autofocus value="<?php echo valuereturn('svissueno'); ?>" >

                <label>Issue date:</label>
                <?php echo valuerequired($_SESSION['svdate']) ?>
                    <input type="date" name="txtdate">

                <label>Introduction</label>
                    <?php echo valuerequired($_SESSION['svintro']) ?>
                    <textarea name="txtintro" ><?php echo valuereturn('svintro'); ?></textarea>
                        <script>toolbar("txtintro");</script>

             </fieldset>

             <fieldset>
                <legend>Academic Messages</legend>

                <label>Message from academic head Cape Town</label>
                    <?php echo valuerequired($_SESSION['svacheadcpt']) ?>
                    <textarea type="text" name="txtacheadcpt" ><?php echo valuereturn('svacheadcpt'); ?></textarea>
                        <script>toolbar("txtacheadcpt");</script> 

                <label>Message from academic head Johannesburg</label>
                <?php echo valuerequired($_SESSION['svacheadjhb']) ?>
                    <textarea type="text" name="txtacheadjhb" ><?php echo valuereturn('svacheadjhb'); ?></textarea>
                        <script>toolbar("txtacheadjhb");</script>


             </fieldset>
```

And the function can be seen below

```
function valuerequired($vsessionkey){

    if(isset($_SESSION[$vsessionkey]) && $_SESSION[$vsessionkey] == 'na') {
        echo '<div class="warning_msg">Value Required</div>'; }

    }
```

The problem is that if I input no data into 'vissueno' my warning div displays but this is not the case on any of the others.

I am new to PHP, would I need to use a for each? I am slightly confused as to where to go from here to fix this.

I have tried using jquery(succesful) but want to learn the PHP way

Comment: you do something strange cause you try to echo function result. But function didn't return any value - it make echo itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php echo valuerequired($_SESSION['svintro']) ?>
```

are you sure that there is no mistake? Maybe

```
 <?php echo valuerequired('svintro') ?>
```

at other places the same

P.S. you do something strange cause you try to echo function result. But function didn't return any value - it make echo itself

Comment: Thank you so much, that is just a lack of concentration on my behalf :)

Comment: It's better show your code at codereview -- echo from function isn't good idea. Also you do something strange cause you try to echo function result. But function didn't return any value - it make echo itself

Answer (score 0):

[Vasiliy Vanchuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3400830/vasiliy-vanchuk) Answer is correct. You need to pass the name of the $_SESSION variable you want to check.